# How to get the next row value in another column

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, ssms

I have Table called Opp Table

---

```
   OppID         actualclosedate   
--------------------------------------
    1            10-March
```

I have a Table called stagechange

```
--------------------------------------
   OppID      Stage       createdon   
--------------------------------------
    1         Propsect    1-Jan        
    1         Qualify     15-Jan       
    1         Develop     25-Jan       
    1         Qualify     9-Feb       
    1         Develop     7-March     
    1         Prospect    9-April
```

How Can I create a new column and get the next row value that is in createdon column; to have something like this. If there is no more next values, we get the date from other table like actual close date in Opp Table

```
--------------------------------------
   OppID      Stage       createdon   newcolumn 
--------------------------------------
    1         Propsect    1-Jan        15-Jan 
    1         Qualify     15-Jan       25-Jan 
    1         Develop     25-Jan       9-Feb    
    1         Qualify     9-Feb        7-March    
    1         Develop     7-March      9-April 
    1         Prospect    9-April     10-March ----(actualclosedate)
```

Comment: What is the type of `createdon` column?

Comment: Please tag with the database you are using.

Comment: Tip: It's helpful to tag database questions with both the appropriate software (MySQL, Oracle, DB2, ...) and version, e.g. `sql-server-2014`. Differences in syntax and features often affect the answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will replace the final/missing date with `actualclosedate`

```
Select A.*
      ,NewColumn = IsNull(Lead(creaton) over (Partition By A.OppID Order By A.CreateOn),B.actualclosedate)
 From  stagechange A
 Join  Opp         B on A.OppID=B.OppID
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming `createdOn` is stored as a valid date/time type and by *next* you mean next by this column, then just use `lead()`:

```
select sc.*,
       lead(createdOn) over (partition by OppId order by createdOn) as next_created_on
from stagechange sc;
```

This assumes (although not explicitly stated in the question) that you want the next date *per `OppId`*.

`lead()` is an ANSI standard function available in most, but not all databases.

Answer (score 0):

you can use the COALESCE fonction https://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/ms190349.aspx